# Локализация centos 7

Tags: linux, локализация

Помогите, не могу поставить русскую локаль.
Пишу в /etc/sysconfig/i18n

```
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
SUPPORTED="ru_RU.UTF-8:ru_RU:ru"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Делаю реконект по ssh но результата нет, пробовал перезагружать сервер но всеровно остался англ. язык, раньше у меня все выходило...
locale -a | grep ru показует:

```
ru_RU
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
russian
ru_UA
ru_UA.koi8u
ru_UA.utf8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

согласно приведённому выводу программы `locale`, русская локаль уже стоит.
получать (где возможно) сообщения на русском можно, экспортировав переменную `LC_ALL` соответствующего содержания:

```
$ ls asdf
ls: cannot access asdf: No such file or directory
$ export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
$ ls asdf
ls: невозможно получить доступ к asdf: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

команду экспортирования, чтобы не вводить каждый раз, можно добавить, например, в `~/.bashrc`:

```
$ echo 'export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc
```

p.s. текущие значения переменных окружения, относящихся к локализации, можно посмотреть с помощью той же программы `locale`, запущенной без параметров.

Answer (score 2):

Искал ответ на данный вопрос и не нашел.

Сделал так. Для локализации *CentOS 7* необходимо создать файл:

```
/etc/locale.conf
```

внести содержимое:

```
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
SUPPORTED="ru_RU.UTF-8:ru_RU:ru"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Сохранить и перезагрузить.
И все!