# Можно ли и как поменять системный locale для конкретной программы в linux?

Tags: linux, локализация, locale

Есть языковые настройки в linux, а есть программа А, которая применяет их для отображения дат в виде mm/dd/yyyy.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы для одной лишь конкретной программы А языковые настройки были отличны от всей остальной системы? Т.е. для всей системы LANG=en_US.UTF-8, а для неё чтобы LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8.

Это возможно и как?

Comment: Установить в терминале или скрипте соответствующую переменную окружения и потом запустить нужную программу

Comment: @andreymal благодарю, от этой информации и будут отталкиваться. Оформите ответом, помечу верным.

Comment: Можно в одну строку выполнить (удобно для .desktop файла): `env LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 программа`.

Comment: ответ уже дан многократно (в том числе и мною, например [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763091/178576) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423941/178576)). проблематично найти именно похожий вопрос-дубликат.